# Understanding the Categorical Coproduct

Tags: category-theory

From *Categories for the Working Mathematician* pg. 64:

[image]

**Question 1:** How do we know that $C(b,c)^X$ makes sense? That is, how do we know that $C(b,c)$ is a category so that $C(b,c)^X$ can be a functor category?

**Question 2:** In $\mathbf{Set}$, wouldn't $X \cdot Y = \amalg_{x \in X} Y = \bigcup_{x \in X} Y = Y$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$C(b,c)$ is not a category: its a *set*. $C(b,c)^X$ is the *set* of functions from $X$ to $C(b,c)$.

$\bigcup_{x \in X} Y$ is not a *disjoint* union, and so it is not a coproduct $\coprod_{x \in X} Y$.

The usual trick for writing coproducts in **Set** in terms of a union is

$$ \coprod_{\iota \in I} S_\iota \cong
\coprod_{\iota \in I} \left( \{ \iota \} \times S_\iota \right) \cong \bigcup_{\iota \in I} \left( \{ \iota \} \times S_{\iota} \right) $$

since $\{ \iota \} \times S_{\iota} \cong S_\iota$, and all of the terms of the union are guaranteed to be disjoint.

Comment: I would add (though I hasten to mention there's no reason to do this) if you really, really wanted it to be a functor category, then you can view a set as a discrete category and the functors between such would be in correspondence with set functions.